# Firebase notEqualTo alternative in schema

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating app using Firebase database. This app is very similar to Tinder. You simply rate profiles and I need to query database for profile that user doesn't rated yet. My schema looks like this:

```
{
   users: {
      user1: {
         alreadyRated: {user2: true, user3: true}
      },
      user2: {
         alreadyRated: {user1: true}
      }
   },
   userProfiles: {
      user1: {
         name: "John",
         age: 20,
         ...
      },
      user2: {
         name: "Jane",
         age: 30,
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

So, if I am user2 I want get all profiles that I doesn't rated yet, in my example I want user3 profile. How to do that? Now I am downloading all profiles and filtering it on client side, but it's not good solution, because there could be hundred or thousands profiles in future. I think I should change my database schema, but I don't know how.

Thank you for ideas.

Comment: What platform are you coding on as there are a number of ways to handle this via code as well and via an alternate structure.

Comment: Javascript, Ionic 2

Comment: Hi @DanielSuchý, Have you found any solution to this?